# WM_KEYDOWN in WndProc - doesn't trigger

Tags: c++builder, keydown, wndproc

I am trying to capture `WM_KEYDOWN` to process some keyboard events at the Form level. I know I can use `KeyPreview=true` and use the `OnKeyDown` event of `TForm`. However, I'd like to do it in the `WndProc()` to simplify event processing in a single function. The problem is, it doesn't fire in the `WndProc()`. Is there a particular reason why it doesn't? Aside from using `BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP` to handle `WM_KEYDOWN`, is there another way?

```cpp
void __fastcall TForm1::WndProc(TMessage &fMessage)
{
    switch (fMessage.Msg)
    {
        default:            break;

        case WM_KEYDOWN:    {
            TWMKeyDown KDMsg = reinterpret_cast<TWMKeyDown&>(fMessage);
            TShiftState KDSs = KeyDataToShiftState(KDMsg.KeyData); 

            if (KDMsg.CharCode == 'C' && KDSs.operator ==(TShiftState() << ssCtrl))
            {
                // Process CTRL+C key
                fMessage.Result = 1;
                return;
            }
        }
        break;
    }

    TForm::WndProc(fMessage);
}
```

Comment: On a side note, `KDSs.operator ==(TShiftState() << ssCtrl)` should be written as `KDSs == (TShiftState() << ssCtrl)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keyboard (and mouse) messages are posted to the window that has input focus. If a `TForm` has a child control that has the focus, the messages will go directly to the child's `WndProc`, not the Form's `WndProc`.

That is where `KeyPreview` comes into play. When true, it tells child controls to forward their keyboard messages to their parent `TForm` for processing.

Otherwise, you can alternatively use the `TApplication(Events)::OnMessage` event to handle input messages before they are dispatched to their target windows.